# I can't uninstall elasticsearch from Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, elasticsearch

In Apps & Features, I try to uninstall Elasticsearch 7.6.1. It seems like uninstalling but rewinds back at the end of the progress. I only got a warning once: "You need to be an admin to delete this", but mostly there's no feedback when it puts the file back.

I'm the admin of my computer.

I checked Elasticsearch service, it's not running. No related task in Task Manager, either.

What would you suggest?

Comment: Try to remember how it was installed at first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer.

First go to the services list, and find the service and open properties windows. Find the name of the service (Elasticsearch in my computer). Than, open command prompt as admin. Delete the service:

```
sc delete Elasticsearch
```

After that you can directly uninstall Elasticsearch from Add or Remove Programs panel.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot uninstall elastic search when service not removed
This article explain  it:
https://bartwullems.blogspot.com/2017/05/tfs-2017how-to-uninstall-elasticsearch.html?m=1